# Kill process winword

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, ms-word, kill-process

To check if a process hangs Word, through a VB.Net 2003 project, I create a thread that makes process control (in question). If after a certain number of milliseconds that the process is still active, I kill the process from the thread. The system tells me "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception", 'Access Denied'

The code is as follows:

This is the code Vb:

```
Imports  System
Imports  System.Threading
Imports  System.Threading.Thread
Imports  System.Security.Permissions
Public Class  ThreadMain
Public  strdotName AsString
Public  strdocName AsString
Public  sXML AsString
Public  idProcesso AsInteger
Public  terminate AsInteger
Public docName AsString
Public  kk AsInteger
Public  finito AsBoolean= False
Public Function LaunchThread() AsInteger
Dim myT2 As Threading.Thread
myT2 = New Threading.Thread(AddressOfMe.DoWork)
myT2.IsBackground = True
myT2.Start()
Try
Console.WriteLine("Finito: {0}", finito)
Catch  Ex As  Exception
End Try
Return terminate
End Function
*-------**
Private Sub DoWork()
Dim  j AsInteger
Dim  errore AsString
Dim  trovato AsBoolean
Dim  colProcess AsProcess
Dim  nomeProcess AsProcess()
Dim  chiusura AsBoolean
Try
For  j = 100 To  20000
colProcess = Process.GetProcessById(idProcesso)
If  Not  colProcess IsNothingThen
j = j + 1000
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
trovato = True
Else
trovato = False
End If
Next
If  trovato Then
chiusura = colProcess.CloseMainWindow()
colProcess.Close()
Process.GetProcessById(idProcesso).Kill()
terminate = 1
End If
Catch ex As Exception
errore = ex.ToString
terminate = 2
End Try
End Sub 'DoWork
```

Comment: Do you have administrator privileges? Is the process you are trying to kill on a remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

The "idProcesso" variable isn't assigned anywhere in the code.  Which probably means that its value is still zero.  Which means that you are trying to kill the "System" process.  Which is a fake process that encapsulates the kernel components of Windows.  Killing Windows like that isn't possible, you'll always get an AccessDenied exception, regardless of your user rights.

You'll need to use Process.GetProcessesByName() to target a specific process.

If this was meant as a workaround to get Word to exit when you use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace then this is only a good way to terminate your own program with an unhandled exception.  Or for that matter another instance of Word that the user is working with.  She won't appreciate losing her work much.